# Why does the center of the screen gradually shift to the side?

Tags: playstation-vr

I've been playing with my new PSVR and I've noticed that sometimes (not consistently), the center of my view gradually shifts to the left, to the point where after half an hour or so, I am sitting sideways on the couch to look "forward". I know that some games allow you to hold the Options button to re-center the view, but not all of them do.

In Rigs and Thumper, at least, attempting to reset the center of view in these games will only fix the rotation around the X and Z axes, even though I really need it to be shifted around the Y axis. In order to reset it correctly, I have to close and reopen the games themselves. The startup time for Rigs, at least, is a few minutes, and I'd prefer not to have to have to restart it every hour or less.

Does anyone know what is causing this? If it's a bug with the hardware/software, is there any way to fix it without closing and reopening the game?

Comment: It's something I noticed with my DS4 when using the onscreen keyboard. For some weird reason, the cursor keeps wandering to the left, forcing me to turn right or reset the cursor every 10 seconds. No idea why that is, but it's possibly related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sony claims that the camera can work at 8 or 9 feet out but when I sit on my couch that far away I get the same drift issue.  I put a chair in front of the couch, in the 5 to 6 foot 'sweet spot' of distance from the camera, and the view drift was almost entirely eliminated.  It's still off by a few degrees, maybe less than ten, so they still have some work to do.

I would recommend making sure you're seated between 5 and 6 feet away, lights are dimmed if possible, and fully power off your PS4 (maybe even pull the cord afterward for a few seconds) and restart it before trying the headset again.

If you notice any "jumping" where the tracking on a controller seems to warp across the screen instead of just wobbling in place, make sure to power down for that as well.  There seems to be a tendency to have some background stuff going on in the PS4 that affects the camera operation and sometimes makes the feed stutter.

Still, if you have the time don't hesitate to call Sony (call them, don't use the web chat) and troubleshoot it with them.  They need to know it's a prevalent issue so that they will work on a fix.  They're open until 10 PM Pacific so you should be able to get help even in the evenings, you're not limited to U.S. business hours.

Their phone number is 1-800-345-7669 and the link to their troubleshooting guide for PSVR is https://support.us.playstation.com/articles/en_US/Decision_Tree/PS-VR-Help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after the first day of owning my PSVR.

What helped me:

- Make sure you are in the center of the camera.
- Make sure you are looking straight at the camera / the camera is straight towards you. Even a slight angle can cause this drift. (In my case, I found out that both my couch and the TV at which the camera was fixed were not straight.)
- If nothing helps, reset the PS4 settings to factory settings. Your games and progress will remain, but you might have to login to PSN again and enter some settings like network again. However, this seems to help in many cases of persistent drift.